# SET Expression for YTD calculation

Tags: qlikview

I have a formula in excel as

```
=IF(K4=0,0,IF(F4=0,AVERAGE(G4:K4),AVERAGE(G4:K4)/F4))
```

where `G4` to `K4` are the values from January to May and `F4` is the yearly target(Target1TR).

`G4` to `R4` contains the monthly values from Jan to Dec.

I need to make a qlikview expression for that excel formula. I have written the `SET` expressoin below but it is not giving me correct results.

Here I am first trying to write : `AVERAGE(G4:K4)/F4`

```
=(sum({$<MonthNo={'>=$(=min({$<Month=>}MonthNo))'}>}[1TR])/max(MonthNo))/Target1TR
```

Comment: MonthNo is used to denote numbers to month. Here 1 is for Jan incremental by 1 till Dec. Max value is 12 for MonthNo which is December.

Comment: Can you add a minimized example of your data as a inline load script. That helps to help you.

Comment: If your data format hasn't changed this is going to be ugly... You essentially need to transpose your table so that you have  a `Month` column containing the month name, a `Sales` column (or whatever you data values actually are) containing the values, and then a `Target` column which would be constant over all values in the same year and would contain your yearly target amount.  Then you would have rows for each month of data you have.  If that was your data format, you could do `if(avg(target) > 0, sum(sales)/avg(target), avg(sales))`

Comment: Then you just need to select Jan - May in your Month list box to get the answer to your question.

Comment: I transposed my table. Do I need to create a calculated Dimension for the YTD with if(avg(target) > 0, sum(sales)/avg(target), avg(sales)) ? This is giving an error in calculation

Comment: Your YTD would be handled by your selections in a listbox.  For example, you could create a text object and set the text expression to the formula I wrote above with a preceding '='.  Then as you select month from your 'month` list box, the total the value in the text object would update accordingly.  What error are you getting?